# Restart workflow using a field?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, workflow, designer-workflow

I'm fairly new to workflows and SP Designer but know how they work. Based on a quick course I took online, one recommendation to kick off a workflow was to use a Date field and have the workflow fire when a date is entered. I was going to name this field "Initiation Date" and have the administrator fill this out as part of their business process.

Here is my question. My system is using an Access back end and will be where my administrator will spend most of their time. What would be a good way to give her the ability to "restart" a workflow without going into SharePoint and manually restarting it? The tables in Access are linked to SharePoint lists, so the data is in both places and kept in sync. Therefore I could make a change to a particular field in Access and have it start the workflow, but I'm less sure about a good way to restart it in a similar fashion, and be able to do this multiple times if necessary.

Scenario:
Workflow is used to gather reviews on someone's performance. Admin fills out basic details and before saving, enters an Initiation Date. Workflow begins, follows a series of steps, and eventually closes when the reviewer finishes their work. Problem is, some people want to be able to reopen their review and change their data. This would mean restarting the workflow as it also controls permissions on that item and whether it can be edited.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you have some sort of status field?  If so, using a change item workflow to check this field anytime the item is modified should work.  Your admin would just change the status back to In Progress in the Access DB, or whatever status indicates that it's open.  Change item workflow would run: if Status = In Progress, do XYZ.

Comment: Hmm I see! Let me test this out! So the workflow would be set to run on new items and changed items, and the first condition would check to see if Status field = Started. Correct?